# Command \example already defined

Tags: lyx, theorems, amsthm

I cannot use `\example` from any of the `Theorems` modules because LaTeX says `"Command \example already defined"` to the line `\newtheorem{example}[thm]{\protect\examplename}` generated by Lyx. I am using Lyx 2.2.2 on Mac. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Unless you are using some fancy packages `\examplename` is undefined.

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the *Paper (Standard Class)* document class together with *Theorems (AMS)* module, the latter defines the `example` environment which conflicts with the document class (since it's already defined).

Unfortunately it does not help placing any corrections in the Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble since the User specified LaTeX commands section (this contains whatever you place in the preamble) is only inserted *after*

```
\newtheorem{example}[thm]{\protect\examplename}
```

To fix this, you have to address the module-specific definition via a Local Layout:

```
Format 60
Style Example
    CopyStyle             Definition
    LatexName             example
    LabelString           "Example \thetheorem."
    Preamble
      \theoremstyle{definition}
      \let\example\relax% Remove any existing example functionality
      \newtheorem{example}[thm]{\protect\examplename}
    EndPreamble
    LangPreamble
      \providecommand{\examplename}{_(Example)}
    EndLangPreamble
    BabelPreamble
      \addto\captions$$lang{\renewcommand{\examplename}{_(Example)}}
    EndBabelPreamble
End
```

The only addition to this local layout (fix) is the insertion of

```
\let\example\relax
```

which removes any existing `example` environment definitions. This allows `\newtheorem{example}` to function as expected, without having to change environments or mess with menu items.

Comment: Thanks Werner. I ended up using article instead of paper

Answer (score 0):

Here is my quick fix. Place the definition of `\exmpl` in the preamble

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exmpl}{\protect\examplename}[section]
\providecommand{\examplename}{Example}
```

And then wrap examples in your text like so:

`\begin{exmpl}` "body of the example" `\end{exmpl}`. LaTeX code should be in Tex code block (cmd+L on Mac).

There is another solution on the [Lyx bug tracker](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8921). The problem is that `Paper` class defines `\example`.

Comment: While this may work, you're circumventing the ease of LyX's environment selection in the menu.